# Where do .CAB files go on my web server?

Tags: activex, cab

I am working on an ASP Classic site that uses 3rd party ActiveX controls.  I've never worked with ActiveX controls before and I'm not sure where to put the .CAB files on my web server to get them to install through IE when IE can't run the objects.
Could someone point me in the right direction?
The code in my page to load the object looks like this:

`<object id="Printer" classid="CLSID:402C09CD-68ED-48B0-B008-E7B01DDBD2D5" codebase="RawDataPrinter.CAB#version=2,0,0,0">
        </object>`

Where do I put that "RawDataPrinter.CAB" file on my server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the server standpoint, the CAB files are just data files. They're not executed on the server - they're installed and executed on the client, that's the whole point. So place them anywere you want. For example, create a subfolder called "cab" under the root of your website and place them there.

If ActiveX (AKA "objects") is disabled in IE, then you have to duplicate the desired functionality in ASP. Depending on the nature of the project, it may or may not be possible.

Comment: So the part of my code that says `codebase = "RawDataPrinter.CAB"` is pointing to a file called RawDataPrinter.CAB in the same directory as my ASP file?
If I have it under www.mywebsite.com/cabs/rawdataprinter.cab then my code should say `codebase='www.mywebsite.com/cabs/rawdataprinter.cab'`?

Comment: Yes. The same rules apply as for images and styles and scripts and whatnot. The path can be relative (or no path at all), from the site root, or full URL. In your case, no path at all means "in the same directory as the current file".